# what's difference between "filter and aggs" and "filter in aggs"

Tags: elasticsearch

I got two ways to aggs my data.

First, i filter mysql data and aggs it

Second ,i aggs data which is filtered in aggs.
as below:

I found different result and I don't know why.

Anyone can explain it ?

[image: case 1]

[image: case 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_scoping_aggregations.html)

> By default, aggregations operate in the same scope as the query. Put another way, aggregations are calculated on the set of documents that match your query.

so in the first case, you are getting documents which match your criteria of `"site_id" : 1167639` and then `aggregation` is performed on those documents.

In the second case, you have not specified any query so by default it is `match_all` query and you get back all the documents in your `hits` which is 65773792. Then you use [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) to narrow down your aggregation criteria.

Comment: Briefly, in first case OP narrows down results and then aggregates, in second query OP aggregates EVERYTHING and then filters aggs, which is obiviously going to run slower.

Comment: in second query OP aggregates EVERYTHING and then filters aggs !!!  I got it . I thought that in second case  query is "match_all" ,and filter in aggs should filter its result  !!!